# Magento 2 Get Tax Amount is 0.000 in cart page ?

Tags: magento2, shipping-tax, taxes, tax-calculation

I get tax amount in cart page but it's 0.000.Why ?
Can anyone help me ?

```
print_r($this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getBaseTaxAmount());
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you add the tax rule/percentage in admin?

Comment: yes.i just want to get tax = 8 $.

Answer (score 0):

i think, this is happend just because of you enabled tax rates for diffrent diffrent country and states.

```
first check in your admin settings->
```

**STEP:1** logIn in your **admin panel**

**STEP:2** stroes->taxes->Tax Zones and Rates

**STEP:3** here you can check that have you mentined tax rate in respect of country and state or not?

**Note:** if you give tax rate in admin settings then you should delete that record

i hope this could help you.

Comment: i have set taxes rule, my idea is when i get taxamount in checkout cart but it received value is 0.000 (expected 8,17$) please see img.

Answer (score 0):

Confirm your configuration setting in admin as below.

**Admin > Store > Configuration > Sales > Tax > Tax Classes > Default Tax Class for Product.**

Make sure your product is taxable.

And also there is all setting are available for product **including tax** **excluding tax**, Shipping **including tax** **excluding tax** etc..

Comment: i have set taxes rule, my idea is when i get taxamount in checkout cart but it received value is 0.000 (expected 8,17$) please see img.

Comment: I have checked in image can't find value 0.000, i can see `subtotal 99.00` `shipping 5.00` `Tax 8.70`

Comment: Are talking about your `Price` and `Subtotal` are display same?

Comment: yes.expected get tax amount is 8.17 but when i get taxamount  $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getBaseTaxAmount()). it's 0.000

Comment: It means your `price` is showing excluding `Tax` right?

Comment: when i get grandtotal and subtotal. they are display same!

Comment: i want to get value tax.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83777/discussion-between-chirag-patel-and-thanh-trung-to).

Comment: did you displayed tax value